How do I change the padding in the blocknote editor
How can I change the padding (shown) in the blocknotejs BlockNoteView component?
The padding seems to be set to accommodate the side menu, but isn't needed with the editable = { false } attribute.
I want to narrow the left padding to about 3px. It is currently double digits in width.

Never mind, it turns out to be quite simple. Add a style element as follows in the read-only context (using jsx):
            <style>
                {
                    `.bn-editor {
                        padding-inline: 0;
                    }`
                }
            </style>

